# Are there non-trivial "already-up-to-date" merges?

Tags: git, git-merge

Suppose you `git merge alt` so that the "alt" branch merges into the "master" branch.

Suppose you then immediate `git merge alt`.  You will receive the console message "Already up to date."

**Question:** Are there any other less trivial scenarios where you can run into this sort of degenerate merge?

Comment: "Already up to date" when running `git merge` or `git rebase` simply means that the branch you want to merge or rebase on is already reachable from the current HEAD.  In the situation you describe, it's one of the parents of the current HEAD commit, but it can also be further up in the history.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you merge in a branch that is ahead of the branch you merge in second. For example:

`git checkout master` - On the master branch
`git checkout -b testA` - Create and swap to branch A
`touch a.txt && git add a.txt && git commit -m "Test A"` - Create `a.txt` and commit

`git checkout -b testB` - Create and swap to branch B (starting at branch A)
`touch b.txt && git add b.txt && git commit -m "Test B"` - Create `b.txt` and commit

History now looks like this:

.. - {master} - {testA} - {testB}

`git checkout master`

`git merge testB` -- By doing this, we also bring in the commit from TestA

History now looks like this:

.. - {testA} - {testB,master}

Running `git merge testA` will give the result 'already up to date', as master already contains all commits on branch `testA`